# cpu vs gpu render times

Tags: rendering, gpu

I recently built a fairly powerful pc that includes an i9 with 28 threads.  It was so fast that I decided to not also invest in a state of the art video card.
However, I recently bought an RTX2070 (8G) so my VR headset would run and was frankly surprised and disappointed to find that the CUDA was only slightly faster than the CPU alone, maybe 25%.  Optix was a little slower so been sticking with the the CUDA.
This is a Win 10 pc, 32G, and the file is about 1G in size, with lots of object-instanced particles for trees and vegetation from linked library.
Is something maybe wrong or is my i9 just that much more powerful?  One reason I stuck with the CPU approach is no memory limitations.

Answer (score 2):

It makes total sense. It is common to overestimate the capabilities of GPUs

Even though in general a single core is not as efficient as is a single GPU. The big advantage of multithreading comes on how many processes are running simultaneously.

Rendering 28 small tiles in parallel on CPU vs a single larger one on GPU might not give the GPU much of an advantage.

Now, if you had more than one GPU, you would see a substantial increase in render speed. 2 GPUs will render in half the time as one.

Answer (score 1):

25% speed increase is very good for a non-top video card versus a top processor.

Optix support is at earlier stage of development and in further it should beat CUDA render.

To deal with memory limit on GPU try to reduce render tile size.

Comment: thanks for the reality check!  I did a lot more variation tests last night and tile size is extremely important.  I was able to get the card to take almost exactly the same amount of time as the CPU, so used together in CUDA I have dropped my render times in half, which feels like a win to me!